# Meteor Facebook login not working after deploying to meteor.com

Tags: deployment, meteor, facebook-login

I have a meteor app that I, and Facebook login works on development. I deployed using the meteor deploy domain.meteor.com commands, but when I go to http://domain.meteor.com, clicking the button does nothing. What's going on?

From what I read, I need to add a settings.json file and deploy with this, but what do I put in this file? Any tutorial on this? I also read some things about setting the ROOT_URL, but am not really sure what this means.